# Fit a simulation python

Tags: python, list, optimization, simulation

I am trying to fit a simulation to empirical data, given the number of parameters of the model brute force is impossible. What are the ressources available to fit a simulation?
The simulations is a python fonction (not to be be mistaken with math function) which outputs a list. I want this list to be as close as possible to an other list (empirical data).

I don't think scipy.optimize works well because it is not a mathematical function but a simulation (impossible to give a function of it). Brute force will require about 5000 simulations which is impractical.

```py
def sim(conta = 0.2, recov = 0.01, D = 600, sig = 3, risk_aversion = 0.05, over_conf = 0.05, power_narr = 5, length = 125, n_k = 0.997, shocks = [8]+[0]*5+[8]+[0]*5+[15]+[0]*5+[40]+[0]*5+[40]+[0]*5, no_len = 25, u = [0.35,0.35,0.15,0.15], w = [1,1,0.1,0.1], ø = 0.9 ):


"""those are the parameters of the simulation, some are floats, others lists"""
 
"""
simulation going on here
"""

return my_list
```

## i want to make this list fit another list by varying the parameters

I expect the output of this fit to be the list of the best parameters of the simulation.

Comment: when you say your using a simulation rather than a function I assume you are using some sort of random number generator so the same inputs don't always return the same outputs? if so could you optimize for a fixed seed?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use scipy optimize, and actually many other much more robust libraries than the ones mentioned in other answers, such as Mystic (https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic) or lmfit (https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py), just to mention a couple.

Whether your objective function is a mathematical function, a result from a simulation, an output of an external program or the outcome of the French-fries making machine is irrelevant. The only questions you should ask yourself are:

1. Is expensive is it to evaluate the objective function? If it takes half a second, then even brute force is ok. I have run scipy and Mystic against external programs (reservoir simulators) and each function evaluation can easily require hours.
2. How likely is it that your objective function has many, many local optima?

The answers to these two questions may steer you towards a specific set of solvers: I.e., local optimization (faster but you run the risk of getting a local minimum) or global optimization (takes more function evaluations to explore the search space but may give you a better fit).

That said, your objective function can easily be rewritten to make it a target for an optimization algorithm:

```
def sim(x, my_target_array):

    # calculation stuff here
    return ((numpy.array(my_list) - my_target_array)**2).sum()
```

Andrea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stochastic methods:

- [Stochastic gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) (an [example](https://alpynepyano.github.io/healthyNumerics/posts/gradient-descent-algorithm.html))
- MCMC Markov Chain Monte Carlo with [PyMC3](https://docs.pymc.io/) (an [example](https://alpynepyano.github.io/healthyNumerics/posts/numerical_stats_03_linear_regression_monte_carlo_method.html))

In any case you need a parametric model. It will be helpful shurely when you write it into your question.